# A question concerning the right side of an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rather silly question...

Usually one writes
$$
\dot{x}=f(x)
$$
when having an autonoumous ODE.

In case that $\Phi(t,x)$ is a flow, i.e. $\Phi(t,x)$ is the maximal solution of the IVP $\dot{x}=f(x)$, what is then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi(t,x)$?

Is it
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)?
$$

But does this make sense? Because it is meant $f(x)=f(x(t))$, isn't it? So I cannot derivate $f$ to $x$?

Comment: $\dot{x} = f(x) \iff \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$ this is surely the case.  What do you mean with $\Phi(t,x)$? Do you mean $\Phi(t,x) = \dot{x} = f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so: $\Phi(t,x)$ is the maximal solution of $\dot{y} = f(y)$ with $y(0) = x$.  So $$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \Phi(t,x) = f(\Phi(t,x)),\ \Phi(0,x) = x$$
and
$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi(t,x) = p(t,x)$$
where $$p(0,x) = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$$
and $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,x) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \Phi(t,x) = f'(\Phi(t,x)) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \Phi(t,x) = f'(\Phi(t,x)) p(t,x)$$

Comment: What is that function $p$?

Comment: Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\text{det}D_x\Phi(h,x)=\text{det}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}D_x\Phi(h,x)$ if the right hand side of the ODE which generates the flow is continiously differentiable?

Comment: @mathfemi: What is $p$?  It is the solution of the differential equation $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,x) = f'(\Phi(t,x)) p(t,x)$ with initial value
$p(0,x) = 1$.